# Total digits number of $2^{1971}$ and $5^{1971}$

Tags: number-theory

I think this is very interesting question. I'm trying to solve this problem for 3 hours. But now I accept the defeat...

> Question:
>
> $2^{1971}$ and $5^{1971}$  numbers are consistently (continuously) written. Find the total digits.

Comment: What do you mean by 'consistently written'?

Comment: continuous.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let there is $k$ digit in $2^{1971}$ and there is $m$ digit in $5^{1971}$.
We must find $k+m$.

Given:
$$10^{k-1}<2^{1971}<10^{k}$$

$$10^{m-1}<5^{1971}<10^{m}$$

The above two relations imply:

$$10^{k+m-2}<10^{1971}<10^{k+m}$$

Finally, $k+m-1=1971 \Rightarrow k+m=1972$

Answer: $1972$ digits are written.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the base-10 logarithm of $2^{1971}$.

This is equal to $1971\log2$.

We have that $\log 2 = 0.30103$, so $1971\log 2 = 593.33$

So our number is $10^{593.33}$. We know that $10^{6}<x<10^{7}$ has $7$ digits.

Using that logic, this number has exactly $\boxed{594}$ digits.

Similarly, we rewrite $5^{1971}$ as $1971 \log 5 = 1377.67$, which has $
\boxed{1378}$ digits.

So $594+1378=\boxed{1972}$ digits.